Default STATIC control height is 8 (dialog units) and text fits, but DrawText() DT_CALCRECT says it's too small?
Inside a dialog, I checked a STATIC control that was created using a default height of 8 dialog units in the resource editor.  The text looks fine.
However, if I check the required text height with DrawText() using DT_CALCRECT, it says it's 3 pixels (presume pixels) too small? It says the existing STATIC control height is 13, but the text rect calculation says it needs to be 16; if it's 16, it looks too high compared to the control that follows it.
Why does it say it needs to be 16 when 13 seems to work ok?
CString cstr=_T("Some Text...");
CRect textsize;
m_ctlStaticText.GetDC()->DrawText(cstr, &textsize, DT_CALCRECT);
CRect rect;
m_ctlStaticText.GetWindowRect(rect);


The DC you get back from GetDC() contains a default font, which is almost certainly not the font the control is actually using.
You need to send the control a WM_GETFONT message to get the font it's using, and then select that font into the DC before measuring the text.
Remember to save the old font handle and restore it before releasing the DC.
